# How to debug selenium test script (C#) in Visual studio while running from Microsoft test manager

Tags: selenium, debugging, microsoft-test-manager

I have selenium testscript (unit test - C#) developed in visual studio and this test script associated with test  case in MTM (Microsoft Test Manager). While running test script from MTM,  script is not stopping at breakpoints in Visual Studio. How to execute test script from MTM in debug mode. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute it from within Visual Studio. Pull up the solution, click Test > Windows >   Test Explorer > to get the test window displayed. Right click on a test and run in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dazed. When I run from Visual studio script will execute from locally in visual studio but I would like to trigger execution from MTM. When ever I run through MTM script is able to execute using Tets Controller and Test Agents but its not stopping at breakpoints in visual studio IDE.

Comment: Trigger your execution from MTM but debug your tests in the IDE.  Are you saying debugging is not working when you run in the IDE? Are you setting break points and running in debug mode? If so and it is not working I would create a new thread on debuging not working for your VS Version.

Comment: I am sorry, may be i did not write correctly. When I debug through IDE its working correctly. But when I trigger execution from MTM , script is executing but not stopping at breakpoints. If you know HP Quality center, QTP tools where if you execute script from Quality Center and put breakpoint in QTP editor, it will stop the execution at break point. Same concept i am checking with Visual studio and MTM.

Comment: I do not think MTM works the same way Micro Focus' tools work. MTM is just a repository. I did see this which was similar. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2388dfe-4103-49fd-b1e5-385d56feec8b/how-to-set-debugger-for-coded-ui-test-from-test-managermtm?forum=vsmantest